EXTI interrupt fires twice on STM32H7
I'm working on a custom board including a STM32H723.
From a FPGA I have a simple signal that pulses for a few 1us at roughly 50kHz.
This goes to an IO pin.
I've hooked up an interrupt EXTI15_10_IRQHandler to trigger on the rising edge.
Inside this routine I increment a volatile variable and toggles an IO pin too.
I clear the pending bit in the EXTI-PR1 register too.
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O2")

volatile unsigned int intspersec = 0;

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
    SCOPE_DEBUG_0;      // Toggles external IO pin
    intspersec++;       // Count em 

    // NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn); // Does not help 
    if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_14)) {
        LL_EXTI_ClearFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_14);
    } // endif

    // Lets waste some time 
    for (volatile unsigned int n=0;n<1;n++) {

    } // endfor
    return; 
}

#pragma GCC pop_options


The interrupt is set to falling edge and I've verified that changing it to rising edge makes the expected difference in the timing.
The problem is that the above interrupt handler is executed twice - see scope shot.

The top trace is the debug IO pin, while the lower (analog) is the input PE14 pin.
The absolute weird part is that if I waste a little more time in the ISR like this
    // Lets waste some time 
    for (volatile unsigned int n=0;n<2;n++) {

    } // endfor


I get a single invocation of the ISR as expected...
I've tried running the code with or without ICache/DCache etc. but it does not seem to make any consistent differences.
We've done many many designs with the STM32 family (F1,F4,G0,L0,L1..) but this is the first H7 design.
Of course we can work around this issue, but I would prefer understanding why it happens, so that it does not end up biting me, in some other form, later.

What does the SCOPE_DEBUG_0 macro look like?

The ScopeDebug macro instantiates a class where the pin is set in the constructor and cleared in the destructor. Gcc ends up emitting a very simple single line of code accessing the BSRR register resulting in two assembly instructions.

So this isn't C but C++?

What I would question in case of C++ is if the compiler is smart enough to handle RAII correctly inside an ISR, given that an ISR might be treated differently than a regular function. C++ is excellent for creating real subtle bugs like that...

Other than that, using interrupt for noisy inputs isn't recommended practice since noise could be triggering the interrupt twice. You could perhaps get away with it if you add a small hardware low-pass RC filter.

Maybe check the flag & any associated flags have cleared before moving on / exiting the ISR / re-enabling the interrupt? I've not delved into the EXTI / HAL but it's possible there's some quirk you're not quite handling or checking. It's possible the clearing of the bit may not happen immediately for example.

@Lundin C or C++ does not matter the assembler output has been verified. Having a noisy signal is not a problem in general. You get more interrupts that you might want but that can be fixed in SW. The noise on this signal is probably due to the probe connection. It's a passive probe. I could hook up an active one but it's not worthwhile.

Does moving the clearing of the interrupt to the very top of the ISR fix it? Also are you running the peripheral bus at a different speed (e.g. much slower) than the CPU clock?

Have you verified how your interrupt fires? You should manually provide high/low levels to that input and see what happens. If you only provide a rising edge, do you get an interrupt? If you only provide a falling edge? Do you get one or two interrupts? "if I waste a little more time in the ISR like this" That would point towards getting interrupts on both edges and if you are slow enough, you just miss the second one.

SCOPE_DEBUG_0;      // Toggles external IO pin This affects the signal on the top trace, right? You have this once in your ISR but we see 4 edges. You state this corresponds to 2 invokations of the ISR, but where is the IO line toggled second time in your ISR?

@JacobSkjoet If the noise is because of the probe, then why does the output signals look perfectly clear? Doubt that is related to passive/active probe, but it could be related to probe ground.

Similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045628/the-right-way-to-clear-an-interrupt-flag-on-stm32

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475009/how-do-i-fix-an-interrupt-that-fires-multiple-times-on-exti9-5

@pmacfarlane The clocks is set up in a fairly normal way - although, with this chip, it's a jungle. Moving the instructions has different effects. The link you posted had the answer. It seems that leaving the interrupt to fast gives you this ghost interrupt. Rereading the EXTI->PR1 into a volatile tmp var seems to do the trick. Thank you ;-)

@lundin It's a mixed signal oscilloscope. The top trace is a digital input ;-). That was why I called the lower one analog. But BTW if you attach an active probe and takes care to do it right you will be amazed on how much of a difference it makes, at least I was the first time around. A passive probe with better probe gnd would have looked a lot better too. This was just sloppy board bring up work, figuring out the delay and timing involved. When the edge on the ISR pin is latched it's latched so noise does not matter and I didn't waste time on the proper measurement setup.

This is normal and is caused by the interrupt clear propagating to NVIC slower than code in rest of ISR is executed.
The standard way to cope with this is to qualify all interrupt sources even if there's only one of them. Clearing the flag causing the interrupt early on helps avoiding the "false" entry, but even if it happens it's then harmless.
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void) {

  // NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn); // Does not help 
  if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_14)) {
    LL_EXTI_ClearFlag_0_31(LL_EXTI_LINE_14);
    SCOPE_DEBUG_0;      // Toggles external IO pin
    intspersec++;       // Count em 
  } // endif
}


I found that reading the PR1 register like volatile unsigned int tmp = EXTI->PR1 resolves the matter. I know it's good practice to clear the pending bit as soon as possible and that checking that the source is what you expect is good practice too. On the other hand you don't want 50000 extra ints/s. Even though they do nothing they consume bandwidth.

I found that reading the PR1 register like volatile unsigned int tmp = EXTI->PR1 resolves the matter. That extra volatile access adds a delay which allows the cleared interrupt to propagate into NVIC. OTOH, there's no guarantee for it, and there are many potential reasons for the exact timing to change, starting with compiler deciding how exactly it interprets the volatile variable, continuing with the complex fabric of 'H7. I think I've discussed these exhaustively in the linked text.

I'm not certain that your description is 100% correct. Played around with wasting time and it took quite some instructions before just getting a single int and not two, so the single read of PR1 is the fastest way I've seen so far. I agree that it's a pain if it all depends on compiler optimizations etc. Anyway it seems to work now and I'll leave it as a semi resolved matter, noting me the risk of being bit by it. BTW Discussed the matter we one of my employees and he was well aware of it - sigh ;-)

My first-hand experience is with the STM32F4. The 'H7 are two orders of magnitude more complex, and so are these kind of effects. The Cortex-M7 processor with its mild super-scalar execution is faster than the M4; and the three-matrix bus system with complex clocks hence resynchronizers is slower than the single matrix in 'F4. Reading from the same peripheral (or any other for that matter) uses that slowness; but still, there are no guarantees. You can try of course the time-wasting method, and use it if you are confident; but qualification of the interrupt source is bullet-proof.

As I said we've done many designs with the STM32 series over the years. Some simple and some extremely complex. The F4 has been the preferred choice unless low power or cost was an issue. The H7 is more complex although two orders of magnitude might be an exaggeration ;-). It took me days to get the SPI bus to work consistently. On other STM32 series it has been a matter of hours. I will qualify the int source but also count them  and flag a warning if too many arrives. Thank for good feedback and ideas. BR Jacob
